# ¿Es posible generar html con sphinx cuando los rst generados están en un folder distinto al código?

Tags: python, docstrings

Estoy generando documentación de un proyecto de Python usando Sphinx y sus correspondientes docstrings.

Actualmente, tengo el código en una carpeta y los htmls generados en otra.

Mi pregunta es si puedo poner los rst en una carpeta distinta al código fuente o si forzosamente tienen que estar en la misma, esto para mantener solamente el código (preferentemente) en un repositorio de github  y la documentación (y rst) en otro repositorio.

Esto es lo que he intentado y funciona:

```sh
# Esto genera los rst
sphinx-apidoc --output-dir /mi_folder_codigo/archivos_rst /mi_folder_codigo/
# Esto genera el html
sphinx-build -v -b html /mi_folder_codigo/ /mi_folder_docs/
```

Cambié lo anterior a esto, pero sólo me genera los rst, pero no los html:

```sh
# Esto genera los rst
sphinx-apidoc --output-dir /mi_folder_docs/ /mi_folder_codigo/
# Esto "debería" generar los html
sphinx-build -v -b html /mi_folder_codigo/ /mi_folder_docs/
```

Incluso, traté cambiando el archivo `index.rst` que está en `/mi_folder_codigo/` junto con `conf.py`

```
.. toctree::
   :glob:

   /mi_folder_docs/*
```

En `conf.py` tengo lo siguiente para la ruta:

```py
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('.'))
```

Y también lo modifiqué a esto:

```py
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('.'))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../mi_folder_docs'))
```

Pero no genera los htmls, sólo como lo puse al principio.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Es posible hacer lo que estoy tratando de hacer?

Cabe aclarar que `mi_folder_docs` y `mi_folder_codigo` están dentro de la misma carpeta:

- carpeta

  - mi_folder_codigo

    - conf.py
    - index.rst
  - mi_folder_docs

¡Gracias!